# I would like to send the wifi wep key automaticaly to laptops on the lan via powershell

Tags: powershell

How do I send the wifi wep key automaticaly to laptops on the lan via powershell

Comment: BTW: WEP provides essentially no security (keys can be found in minutes on a normal laptop). WPA has also been broken (albeit more effort needed). Better to move to WPA2 as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a WMI method on Win32_NetworkAdapter or at least I didn't see one. Since the key is stored encrypted a registry approach wouldn't be useful. Netsh has an option to export a wireless profile which includes the WEP key and you then can add the profile to another laptop.